# PHP file return nothing

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the below code which is connect to MySql, unfortunately it does not return anything. I am wondering what mistake I made.

Her is the code:

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; // Host name 
$username = "*******"; // Mysql username 
$password = "*******"; // Mysql password 
$db_name = "*******"; // Database name 
$tbl_name = "*******"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_set_charset('utf8');

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); //5
$result = mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

$count = 0;
$items;

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $item['name'] = $row['name'];
    $item['address'] = $row['address'];
    $item['latitude'] = $row['latitude'];
    $item['longtude'] = $row['longtude'];
    $items[$count++] = $item;
}

//echo json_encode($items);
echo json_encode($items, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

Please advice me.

Comment: Items should be declared as `$items = [];`. You do not need to set the indices by yourself. `$items[] = $item;` will do much faster.

Comment: I am really new, can you give more explanations

Comment: Check what version of PHP you are using, the `mysql_` api has been removed in *newer* versions of PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I just change the version of PHP.

Thanks